# OpenShift PostgreSQL Database Restore

Tags: postgresql, openshift, restore

I have an OpenShift App that uses the PostgreSQL database.

I want to restore this database with data from a 'live' database.

When running locally, I just drop the database. Then I create the database and then run the restore.

But, when I try and drop the database on OpenShift, it says:

```
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "test" is being accessed by other users
```

So I stopped the OpenShift App and then retried

Now it says:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "test" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/lib/openshift/123456ef0c1e123456789b/postgresql/socket//.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So I have a catch 22 situation.

What is the correct way to restore a PostgreSQL database on OpenShift?

Comment: It seems that stopping OpenShift also stopped the Postgres server which sounds strange. You need to check if that OpenShift thing can be configured to not mess with the database server

Comment: Yes, that would appear to be the case. When I stop the OpenShift App it also stops the PostgreSQL server. But how to get around this...

Comment: Approaching this issue from the postgresql side (rather than openshift), you might want to try https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected

Answer (score 0):

Leave Postgresql running but stop the application that was accessing the database. It's that simple...